# why i need to add double quote to print first and last element of char array in java

Tags: java, arrays, char

Why do I need to add double quote (`" " +`) to print first (`nptel[1]`) and last element (`nptel[nptel.length-1]`) of a char array.

```
char nptel [] = {'J','A','V','A','N','P','T','E','L'};
System.out.println(" " + nptel[1] + nptel[nptel.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java the addition of two chars is interpreted as int following their ascii values. It's equivalent to `(int)'a' + (int)'b'`

By adding the `" " +` in front of the addition, you implicitly cast the chars into strings.
So it's equivalent to `Character.toString('a') + Character.toString('b')`.